# Remove duplicate and most Similar in dataframe pandas python

Tags: python, dataframe, duplicates

I want to remove duplicates and most similar from dataframe

```
df["ID","name","Color"] = {[123,BMW 2017,Black],
                           [124,BMW 2016,Black],
                           [125,KIA,Blue],
                           [126,Mini,Yellow],
                           [127,Skoda,White],
                           [128,BMW,White]}
```

The result should be

```
                          {[123,BMW 2017,Black],
                           [125,KIA,Blue],
                           [126,Mini,Yellow],
                           [127,Skoda,White],
                           [128,BMW,White]}
```

Comment: What are the criteria for "most similar"?  Where is your coding attempt?

Comment: select all cars with respect to the color and the year is not important, so for example: we have
SequenceMatcher(None,"BMW 2017", "BMW 2016").ratio()
 = 0.875
So, this is most similar

Comment: If the year is not important, then you need to split that into a separate column, or at least pre-process your **name** column to remove it.  Split that field into words and compare on the first word only.  "dedup" (remove duplicates) based on those criteria.

Comment: The issue here is "name" column, some values 3 or 4 words, in this case how many columns should I have after splitting!!, I think SequenceMatcher is much better, I tried this using for loop but the performance wasn't good

Comment: You will have no extra columns; this is in-line processing.  You put **name.split()[0]** into your comparison criteria.

Comment: Okay; I'll sweep these comments into an answer so you can accept and retire the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

If the year is not important, then you need to split that into a separate column, or at least pre-process your name column to remove it. Split that field into words and compare on the first word only. "dedup" (remove duplicates) based on those criteria.

You put **name.split()[0]** into your comparison criteria: that splits the string into individual words, but then uses only the first one.